# Название птицы сорокопут

Tags: этимология

В названии хищной  птицы сорокопут читается два слова - сорока и пут.
Схожесть с сорокой очевидна, а причем здесь пут?
Пут - орел, слово из талышского и полагаю, что и роського языка. Роськое мужское имя Путята, Путято - равный, подобный орлу.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Вот одна из версий.

Птица эта напоминает сороку (эти слова из песни не выбрасываю из уважения к автору версии: констатирую, что это не так, к тому же сорока стрекочет всё больше). Что же касается до концовки ***пут***, то она, по всей вероятности, есть «характеристика подражательного пения этих птиц, путающих в своих песнях голоса других пернатых» (К.Н.Карташев. Систематика птиц), и указывает на свойство сорокопутов-пересмешников (один из трёх десятков видов) «**плести путы сорока птицам**», то есть подражать их голосам, вводя тем самым людей, да и самих птиц в заблуждение.

С сорокой птица имеет мало общего: статью не вышла. До орла ей и вовсе далеко.

Comment: Вживую я эту птаху не видел и не слышал, потому мои сравнения  субъективны.

Comment: Как на пение сорокопуты очень разные, так и обличием. В сети можно легко найти.